# How to shutdown an ExecutorService from one of its threads?

Tags: java, executorservice

I want to stop the whole `ExecutorService` if one (specific thread) of the threads managed by it fails with an exception. Is it ok to simply call `ExecutorService#shutdown` from within the thread?

Comment: I don't see why not.  But don't call `awaitTermination` from the worker thread because that is liable to deadlock.

Comment: Be aware that `shutdown` does *not* stop the executor service. No more tasks can be submitted, but all tasks already submitted will continue to execute.

Answer (score 0):

With `Executorservice` , if getting returned data from a thread ( using `.get()` method ) fails with an Exception , an `ExecutionException` will be thrown .
You have 2 case : passing `Runnable` to the `submit` method , or passing a `Callable` , in both of those cases you can use `.get()` method to retrieve data from the thread after execution.

So you can add `.get()` method to all the execution of threads and surround the calls of the `submit` method with a try catch block that handle `ExecutionException` .

This example will explain the idea :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Test {
    static ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            // Callable
            System.out.println(service.submit(() -> {
                return "Hello";
            }).get());

        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            // shutDown the service : if you delete the next line , service will still
            // working
            service.shutdownNow();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            // Runnable
            service.submit(() -> {
                throw new IOException();
            }).get();

        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            // shutDown the service : if you delete the next line , service will still
            // working
            service.shutdownNow();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```